# Implement quartz.net through configuration

Tags: quartz.net

I need to shedule some task through the Quartz.net. I want to configure the trigger and jobdetails  through the config file. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the configuration and/or implementation has changed in Quartz 2.  You will have to include this in your config:

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz"/>
```

in addition to your other configuration settings in the `<quartz>` node. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic2548.html):

> This plugin loads XML file(s) to add jobs and schedule them with triggers as the scheduler is initialized, and can optionally periodically scan the file for changes.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have implemented the following code, however it is showing the error "SchedulerPlugin of type 'Quartz.Plugin.Xml.JobInitializationPlugin, Quartz' could not be instantiated". Not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: @user1053922 I don't have any experience with Quartz.NET (only with Java's Quartz), but I guess there must be some exception somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

if you not have a XML or Config only for the job then remove all keys with value Quartz.Plugin in the Web Config and set only

```
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="XmlConfiguredInstance" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="5" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
```